# Printing a variable and appending it with a line from a file in a loop

Tags: python

I've researched this already but I can't find an exact answer.  I've found answers for appending when there's 2 lists involved but this is different so here goes.

I'm creating a really basic fuzzer but I'm having issues appending the directory names to the end of the address.  Here's what I have so far.

The expected output is as follows;

```
www.website.com/1
www.website.com/2
www.website.com/3
www.website.com/4
```

etc.  But I'm getting something completely different.  Here's the first piece of code I tested.

```
>>> host = "www.website.com/"
>>> path = [line.strip() for line in open("C:/Users/Public/Documents/tester.txt", 'r')]
>>> print str(host) + str(path)
```

which returns the following

```
www.website.com/['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10']
```

The second attempt was this;

```
>>> host = "www.website.com/"
>>> path = [line.strip() for line in open("C:/Users/Public/Documents/tester.txt", 'r')]
>>> for line in path:
print str(host) + str(path)
```

Which returned this;

```
www.website.com/['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10']
www.website.com/['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10']
www.website.com/['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10']
www.website.com/['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10']
www.website.com/['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10']
www.website.com/['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10']
www.website.com/['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10']
www.website.com/['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10']
www.website.com/['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10']
www.website.com/['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10']
```

I can see exactly what's happening and why it's happening but I can't figure out how to arrive at the expected output.  I'll also need to filter out the special characters which I didn't think 'print' would pick up.  Maybe there's different rules for print when it's reading something as a list.

I've thought of stupid complex methods such as counting the lines in the file and then throwing it into a while loop using that count but I'm sure there's something I can use or something I've done wrong.  My Python knowledge isn't fantastic.

Can anybody help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were nearly there , when using the for loop , concatenate the elements from the list (which in your case is in variable 'line') , not the complete list again .

Code -

```
for line in path:
    print str(host) + str(line)
```

Comment: Oh god you're right.  I can blame something like this on the time being 4am right?

Comment: Tried to do it straight away, told me that I couldn't mark as answered for another 6 minutes and then I forgot about the tab but, it's done now.  Thanks for your help.